# QGIS 3.26 - Merge selected features

Tags: qgis, merge

If I use merge selected features, the rule is that the data is automatically taken from the features with the lowest ID. I know that I can manually choose which features to download data from. But is it possible to change this rule, for example, that the data will be taken from the first selected features?

Comment: Which software are you working with? How do you define the first selected feature?

Comment: QGIS 3.26 is used. I manually select, for example, 7 polygons and I want the data to be taken from the first selected polygon.

Comment: Which one is the first selected polygon? The polygon you first clicked at?

Comment: Yes, polygon that is first clicked.

Comment: merged selected features plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/merge_selected_features/

Comment: I don't want to create a new layer.